# Show old price with line-through

Tags: 7, commerce

I have Drupal 7, without Drupal Commerce modules installed, because we are nor e-commerce place. For some items, we need to show up two prices (old_price and new_price). Only for items for new_price filled I need to show up old_price line-trough or with an X on top. I suppose that I need to put some code in someplace, but where?

I have been looking for a module, but all modules are for commerce. I do not want to install commerce and all the pile of commerce modules just to add this feature.

Answer (score 1):

First, create two fields-"Old price" and "new price". Second, use css `text-decoration:line-through;` on the old price field.

Edit:

Based on your comment and clarification, I would suggest using rules and rules bonus pack to look for the "new price field", then have it add a body class to the node.

Your rule will look something like

- Event #1: "when content is created"
- Event #2: "when content is updated"
- Condition #1: "entity has field", then select your "new price" field
- Condition #2: "Data value is empty" and enable "negate"
- Action: "Add body class"

Then in your css add the strikethough based on the extra body class.

This is essentially how the Commerce price savings formatter module works, but without the overhead of using commerce.

Comment: yes I know ...I did it, But I need old-price line-through only if we have new price.

Comment: It works, except the line-through, the color works but not the line,   .field-name-field-price{
 text-decoration: line-through;
 color: red;
}
weird... any ideas?

Comment: I would have a link to see the site to determine it.

Comment: well is modernism.com,  but I am working on a test site.. not real site.. but if you go to modernism.com we would like this action at  item price... just click on an item with price..

Comment: this is a good example... but the rule is not in production..  http://modernism.com/items/39/chandeliers/150-93-french-art-deco-wrought-iron-twist-chandelier

Comment: I'll need to see it with the rule in place to inspect the html

Comment: 72.14.178.74    test.modernism.com   
add this line to your hosts file and go to test.modernism.com

Comment: take a look here   http://test.modernism.com/items/84/architectural/1510-1308-vintage-advertising-metal-neon-sign-letters-grace

Comment: I can see but you'll need to either allow anonymous users to see prices or give me a password. it prompts me to login to see the price.

Comment: it's ok I just created an acccount

Comment: just log in as a visitor..

Comment: what is the body class that is being added by rules?

Comment: I can't see an newly added body class from rules, so I am not sure it is firing. but your css should be .rules-body-class .field-name-field-price .field-item{text-decoration:line-through;}

Comment: ok.. so  I need to add .rules-body-class to the css... let me see if works

Comment: Whatever you added through rules to apply the body class. However I see that rules isn't doing that as I don't see any custom body classes added

Comment: yes...  please, let me know how can I add this classes? special css file name? my theme is adaptivetheme..  I have no style.css file, I have been doing this on field.css file... well I am lost now.. thanks for your help..

Comment: Did you even create the rule? Assign me admin rights to my recently created account and ill take a look on the back end.

Comment: rule is done... see the message on top "... BE CAREFULL....This Item is ON SALE" it come from the rule...

Comment: you are right, I have no added body class,  so I just added.. the name is strike-out-price,,, for now only strikeout is a message on top... so how can I redirect strikeout the old-price?

Comment: my email is mariocantor@gmail.com if you want to cntinue your help.... Thanks!!!

Comment: now I see the body class by rules. now just add .strike-out-price .field-name-field-price .field-item{text-decoration:line-through;} in your css

Comment: NICE  !!!! WORKS!!! almost Done... finally the price is strikeout, but shows up all prices strikeout even prices without sale price..

Comment: Then your rule is setup incorrectly. I'll need access to edit the rule on the backend

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use [the module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_price_savings_formatter) that does this formatting for you.